# Как выделить по умолчанию некоторые элементы из массива yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Создаю элемент `checkBoxList` yii2 в форме. Как выделить по умолчанию некоторые элементы  массива `companiesAll` из массива `companiesSelect`?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idsCompanies')->checkBoxList($companiesAll, [
    'separator' => '<br>'
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете указать это при создании модели, примерно так:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->idsCompanies = ['campaign1', 'campaign2', 'campaing3'];
```

а уже затем передать её во view, где и определена ваша форма

Comment: А как сделать некоторые  элементы выбранными по умолчанию ?

Comment: @ОлегБас ответ выше, когда создаете модель, сразу определяете параметры по-умолчанию для атрибута **idsCompanies**